# Fill form fields with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, autofill, form-fields

I always use this code for fill input value form

```
document.forms[From Number].elements[Element Number].value="something"
```

but it doesn't work in [Hotmail](https://login.live.com/) , [gmail](https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin).
there is a special placeHolder there and I don't know what I do.

Comment: What exactly is the problem that you are trying to solve?

Comment: I want to make an extension to fill fields input forms as auto but it doesn't work very well there